# Delete occurances at the end of a string - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say you have a `NSString *testString = @"Abcd!!!!";`, note the four exclamation marks, how can I delete all exclamation marks as efficiently as possible?

The exclamation marks can be any number of amount, and can only be deleted if they're in consecutive trailing order.

One example might be:
`NSString *testString = @"ABC!D!!!!!";`

The result would then be:
`NSString *result = @"ABC!D";`

Comment: one simple pattern is just say ... "while last is a !, remove last".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't know how many ! you'll be removing from the string, you could do it with a regular expression.

```
NSString *string = @"ABC!D!!!!!";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"!+$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", modifiedString);
```

Regex aren't always the *most* efficient way to solve these sorts of problems, but in this case, I don't think there would be a measurable gain doing it another way.

Comment: Counting them isn't really going to work doing it this way (unless you did a regex capture group, but then things are getting so complicated you're better off using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`. Couldn't you just compare the length of the original string to the length of the modified string?